# Blur on hidden element doesn't remove focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I Use Chrome Version 21.0.1180.89

I have an input that I `.hide()` and call `.blur()` on. the blur event is fired, the input is not actually losing focus.

Is this documented behavior? Is there a good workaround?

I am building a Backbone app where data in a textfield should be saved when the user press enter or the field lose focus. Just like the [TodoMC Backbone demo](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/).

But they get away with it, since they re-build the entire li-eleent from the template every time it changes. I don't want to do that, since it breaks CSS transitions.

Edit:

Most of the relevant Backbone code:

```
var app = app || {};

$(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Todo Item View
    // --------------

    // The DOM element for a todo item...
    app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

        //... is a list tag.
        tagName:  'li',

        // Cache the template function for a single item.
        template: _.template( $('#item-template').html() ),

        // The DOM events specific to an item.
        events: {
            'click .toggle':    'togglecompleted',
            'dblclick label':   'edit',
            'click .destroy':   'clear',
            'keypress .edit':   'updateOnEnter',
            'blur .edit':       'close'
        },

        // Switch this view into `"editing"` mode, displaying the input field.
        edit: function() {
            this.$el.addClass('editing');
            this.input.focus();
        },

        // Close the `"editing"` mode, saving changes to the todo.
        close: function() {
            var value = this.input.val().trim();

            if ( value ) {
                this.model.save({ title: value });
            } else {
                this.clear();
            }

            this.$el.removeClass('editing');
            this.$el.addClass('syncing');
        },

        // If you hit `enter`, we're through editing the item.
        updateOnEnter: function( e ) {
            if ( e.which === ENTER_KEY ) {
                // Stupid hack to trigger a blur only once.
                this.$el.append(this.input.detach());
//              this.close();
            }
        },

        // Remove the item, destroy the model from *localStorage* and delete its view.
        clear: function() {
            this.model.destroy({wait: true});
            this.$el.addClass('deleting');
            this.$el.addClass('syncing');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, that was annoying... :)

Comment: Probably you need to check `if ($(this).is(':visible')) { alert("blur triggered");  }` That way your blur content will be executed only when it is visible.

Comment: @Vega: The Fiddle is not the actual site, just a demo of the problem. The input is not supposed to be visible after you press enter in it, but it stays focused, so as soo as I click anywhere it will fire the blur event again.

Comment: Can you upload it somewhere to show us how your code works?

Comment: As another possible workaround you can add a little delay to the hide element to make it work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/nxtwrld/judJJ/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when you blur a DOM Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887166/what-happens-when-you-blur-a-dom-element)